# Javascript regex /x modifier

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex to extract the referencing URL and the text from an anchor HTML tag:

```
/<a(?:.*?)href=['"](.+)['"](?:.*)>(.+?)<\/a>/x
```

However I noticed the `/x` modifier **doesn't work in Javascript.**

My intention was doing the following:

```
var str = '<a href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow">Google</a>';
var msg = str.replace(/<a(?:.*?)href=['"](.+)['"](?:.*)>(.+?)<\/a>/x, function ($0, $1){
    return 'Hello my name is ' + $1 + 'and my Homepage is: ' + $0; 
});

console.log(msg);
// should print 'Hello my name is Google and my Homepage is http://google.com'
```

This would support any other property inside the anchor tag.

Any ideas how to accomplish a `/x` behavior?

Comment: Why do you need it? It seems superfluous here.

Comment: I don't see how /x would change anything here (what do you expect it to do?)

Comment: Well this is a bad usage example I believe. Keeping it simple I need to extract those 2 values, the URL and the Name

Comment: Using RegEx in JavaScript to extract attributes from HTML has got to be one of the biggest mistakes people make.

Comment: just another futile attempt to parse HTML with REGEX. Don't. Easier and more robust is to use a DOM parser instead.

Comment: **"// should print 'Hello my name is Google and my Homepage is http://google.com'"** No, it should print :`Hello my name is http://google.com" rel="nofollowand my Homepage is: <a href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow">Google</a>`

Comment: If you want to use free spacing mode you can use [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) but I'm not quite sure this is what you really want to do...

Comment: Is a message from an API that comes as a HTML string

Comment: The `/x` modifier of Perl and [Perl-Compatible](http://pcre.org/) Regular Expressions allows you to use whitespace in the expression that, if not escaped, is ignored, and it allows you to use comments in the expression, both of which make expressions easier readable and understandable; the feature is also known as `PCRE_EXTENDED`.  ECMAScript does not support that built-in, but if you ever need it, you can use [JSX:regexp.js](http://PointedEars.de/wsvn/JSX/trunk/regexp.js) which emulates it: `new jsx.regexp.RegExp("…", "x")`. See also the [testcase](http://PointedEars.de/scripts/test/regexp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = '<a href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow">Google</a>';
var myregexp = /<a.*?href=["'](.*?)["'].*?>(.*?)<\/a>/g;
var result = str.replace(myregexp, "Hello my name is $2 and my Homepage is $1");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/97c9x/3/

Comment: Why did you change `["']` to `["|']`?  Now it will match a double-quote, a pipe, or a single-quote.  I'm pretty sure that's not what the OP wanted. ;)